# Making shortcuts on desktop via Intune

Tags: powershell, intune

I am trying to make a  desktop shortcut of a browser via intune. I have 40+ laptops and would like to create desktop shortcut which will open specific site when opened.

I am using .intunewin app which i learned from here: https://tech.nicolonsky.ch/intune-create-desktop-shortcut/

I am stuck creating an install script which is here:

```
%windir%\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file  "CreateDesktopIcon.ps1" -ShortcutTargetPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" -ShortcutDisplayName "Microsoft Edge" -IconFile "%windir%\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe" -ShortcutArguments "https:// (sitename)"
```

I keep getting installation failure on the device. Could someone help me please i am very new.

Edit: The errorcode i am getting is 0x80070000

Comment: It seems the author doesn't let you specify the destinationpath yourself and always creates it on the desktop (either the AllUsers desktop when running as user SYSTEM, or the current users desktop) Strange.. Anyway, please show the errors you receive in full and add these to your question.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. The installation was succesfully completed after reboot and synchronization.